# loop through nested data in object

Tags: jquery

This is my object:

```
var testing =  {
  "total": {
    "q1": "10,000€",
    "q2": "20,000€",
    "q3": "19,000€",
    "q4": "210,000€"
  },
  "new": {
    "q1": "10,000€",
    "q2": "20,000€",
    "q3": "19,000€",
    "q4": "210,000€"
  },
  "renewal": {
    "q1": "10,000€",
    "q2": "20,000€",
    "q3": "19,000€",
    "q4": "210,000€"
  }
}
```

I want to loop through the data associated specifically with "total", I'm not sure how to specifically get the values from `"total"`. The following doesn't work :(

```
    $.each(testing, function(i, item) {
    $("#kpi-table").find('tr.total td').each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).html(item[0].[i]);
      });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="kpi-table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Q1</th>
    <th>Q2</th>
    <th>Q3</th>
    <th>Q4</th>
    <th>Month</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="total">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td class="q1"></td>
      <td class="q2"></td>
      <td class="q3"></td>
      <td class="q4"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
..
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML ?

Comment: is `var testing` reflective of `tr.total td`?

Comment: added HTML @depperm

Comment: Where `item[0]` come from?

Comment: suggest you use console logging to inspect what you are looping and what each callback argument is.

Comment: @user1937021 You've probably solved this already but see https://jsfiddle.net/aqhrocL9/

Comment: @Moob make it as an answer and I'll vote it, that's perfect thanks!